# Ehcache with Spring boot is not working in Test env

Tags: java, spring-boot, ehcache

I am using Spring boot (1.4.2.RELEASE) and Ehcache (2.4.3)

Cache is being used in dev environment but it is not being used(hit) in other environments(test and prod).

Code is as below:

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

On **Main class**, have added below annotation for caching

```
@EnableCaching
public class Application {
```

Under **src/main/resources, ehcache.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd"
     updateCheck="true" monitoring="autodetect" dynamicConfig="true">

    <cache name="languageCache" 
      maxEntriesLocalHeap="20"
      overflowToDisk="false"
      eternal="false" 
      diskPersistent="false"
      memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"/>

     <cache name="countryCache" 
      maxEntriesLocalHeap="280"
      overflowToDisk="false" 
      eternal="false" 
      diskPersistent="false"
      memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"/>
..
..
more entries
 </ehcache>
```

**Cache Config file**

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CacheConfig {

    @Bean
    public CacheManager getEhCacheManager() {
        (new EhCacheCacheManager(getEhCacheFactory().getObject())).getCache("languageCache");
        return new EhCacheCacheManager(getEhCacheFactory().getObject());
    }

    @Bean
    public EhCacheManagerFactoryBean getEhCacheFactory() {
        EhCacheManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new EhCacheManagerFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setConfigLocation(new ClassPathResource("ehcache.xml"));
        factoryBean.setShared(true);
        return factoryBean;
    }
}
```

Few questions on above code:

1) Is it Due to this line

factoryBean.setConfigLocation(new ClassPathResource("ehcache.xml"));

Cache is not being hit /used in any other environment except Dev env?

2) Do we need CacheConfig file at all? or Spring boot will detect Ehcache using annotation(@EnableCaching) on Main Class?

Any suggestion , why cache is not being picked up (some configuration I am missing ?) in other envs?

Thank you

Comment: How do your test and production environments differ to dev ?

Are there any code differences, e.g. different Spring profiles or different Maven build profiles ?

By the way your code looks fine.

Comment: Why are you creating 2 instances of `EhCacheCacheManager` seems like a hack. Your `CacheManager` needs to be named `CacheManager`.

Comment: Hi Paul, yes config param file is different for different environment. But I don't have any configuration for cache in those param files. When I am setting ehcache.xml in CacheConfig.java , should I use something else than ClassPathResource ?

Comment: Can you please suggest how to mock getEhCacheManager in spring boot environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have many `ehcache.xml` in your classpath, it should work. `@EnableCaching` won't work by magic unless you have a JSR107 compliant implementation in your classpath (e.g. Ehcache 3).

Your code works. The only weird part is that you are calling the `getObject()` yourself. It still works but I would have done.

```
@Bean
public CacheManager cacheManager(net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager cacheManager) {
  return new EhCacheCacheManager(cacheManager);
}

@Bean
public EhCacheManagerFactoryBean cacheManagerFactory() {
  EhCacheManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new EhCacheManagerFactoryBean();
  factoryBean.setConfigLocation(new ClassPathResource("ehcache.xml"));
  factoryBean.setShared(true);
  return factoryBean;
}
```

That said, I would have, in fact, done something simpler:

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CacheConfig extends CachingConfigurerSupport {

    @Bean
    @Override
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        return  new EhCacheCacheManager(new net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager());
    }
}
```

Also, note that it is **really really** rare that you really need a shared cache manager. It is shared across the application context already. So it is quite rare (and frequently dangerous) to share it as a singleton.

Comment: Thanks Henri for response, I have two ehcache.xml ( One at path src/main/resources and other at path src/test/resources ) and for Spring-boot to pick Ehcache , I have Ehcache dependency in pom . So do you mean that without  using factoryBean.setConfigLocation(new ClassPathResource("ehcache.xml")) , it should work out? I will try your code.

Comment: No. It's the same. new CacheManager() is taking `ehcache.xml` by default. It is also frequent to have an `ehcache.xml` for test and prod. However, your IDE might use the test one when running locally. Which could explain the difference.

Comment: Thanks Henri, i have cleaned off code and checked that caching is working. Thanks again

Comment: Can you please suggest how to mock getEhCacheManager in spring boot environment?

Comment: I would use a Simple cache instead or no cache.